# Why does running jstack on windows give 'unable to attach to 64 bit process' error'?

Tags: java, windows, multithreading, jvm, jstack

I tried the command

`jstack -l <pid>` and got the following error -

```
unable to attach to 64 bit process' error
```

I then tried this command -

`jstack -F <pid>` and got this error -

```
Attaching to process ID <pid>, please wait...
Error attaching to process: Windbg Error: GetModuleParameters failed!
```

How do I run jstack successfully on Windows? More specifically, I am running Windows 7.

Comment: My guess is you are running `jstack` as a 32-bit process, or as a different user.  I suggest you use the same version of Java as the same user.

Answer (score 0):

Taking Peter's comment above a little further, I found that, on Windows, you have to
- run the jstack process as an administrator
- use the same Java installation for jstack that was used to start the process you want to analyse.

Trying to get a dump from a process running under Java 1.8.0_40-b26 amd64 using jstack from an installation of 1.8.0_111-b14 didn't work. Using jstack from 1.8.0_40-b26 amd64 did.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are running from a different location. You will need to run the command from bin folder of your JDK where jstack is found.